# Using custom variable in GA event tracking

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-analytics, event-tracking

I am trying to get a custom variable into some Event Tracking in a dynamic templating system. It uses information from the URL to use as the variable.

There is nothing coming across into analytics with this script appended. Can anyone see anything wrong with it?

```
jQuery(function iCatGaFunction() {
    jQuery('#catbanner').click(function () {
        var url = jQuery(location).attr('href'); // get the current url
        var iCat = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('/') + 1); // Last index of the url icat reference 
        _gaq.push(['_setCustomVar', 1, 'iCatBanner', iCat]); // GA snippet
    });
});

jQuery('#catbanner').find('a:first').attr('onClick', 'iCatGaFunction()'); // wrap first a href around <img> and call function onclick
```

I followed the instructions here - perhaps something to do with scope? 
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/methods/gaJSApiBasicConfiguration#_gat.GA_Tracker_._setCustomVar

Comment: I see the custom variable. What I do not see is the event tracking.  setCustomVar must be followed by an interaction hit or the value will not be sent.

Comment: @EikePierstorff - are you able to give me an example, please?
Do you mean within that method, after the iCat? or a seperate method in the iCatGaFunction, like this... 

 _gaq.push(['_trackEvent',
      'BannersTracking', // category of activity
      'iCatBanner', // Action
   ]);

Comment: Whereever, as long as it is after the variable is set. At the end of the iCatGaFunction should be fine.

Comment: @EikePierstorff.. In Analytics we've got now:
Event action = iCatBanner 
- but no Event Label??